# How do I stroke a CGContext path with multiple random images

Tags: iphone, random, png, cgcontext

I want to stroke a `CGContext` path using three or four images, but randomly cycle through the images as I'm drawing the path. I want to draw the images INSTEAD!! of drawing the `CGContext` I am now. I have this code so far

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    currentPoint.x = currentPoint.x;
    currentPoint.y = currentPoint.y;
    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), YES);
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brushSizeVal);
    CGContextSetAlpha(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), drawingColorAlpha);
    CGContextSaveGState(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());    //Probably right here
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 
                                                                        drawingColorRed,
                                                                        drawingColorGreen,
                                                                        drawingColorBlue,
                                                                        drawingColorAlpha);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
                                                 lastPoint.x,
                                                 lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 
                                                  currentPoint.x,
                                                  currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    //drawImage is the UIImageView that I am drawing my context to
    NSLog(@"current point x: %d current point y: %d",currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);    //Used for my purposes
    lastPoint = currentPoint;
    mouseMoved++;
```

and

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    if (!optionsDisplayerVisible && canDraw)
     {
        if(!mouseSwiped)
         {
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
                [drawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
                CGContextSetShouldAntialias(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), YES);
                CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
                CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brushSizeVal);
                CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 
                                                                   drawingColorRed,
                                                                   drawingColorGreen,
                                                                   drawingColorBlue,
                                                                   drawingColorAlpha);
                CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
                CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
                CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
                CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
                drawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    //drawImage is the UIImageView that I am drawing to
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Describe what you want more specifically; then please describe what your code actually does in the state you've presented it in.

Comment: Are you intentionally drawing your image over itself each time?

Comment: I want to draw the images instead of drawing the CGContext I am now. If you need more explination then ask.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really explained very clearly what you are trying to do. You are using the word "stroke" while referring to images. You can stroke a path, but not *with* an image. It doesn't make any sense. You can use an image as a mask and a path that specifies which part of the image to mask. You can do that with [CAShapeLayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you are trying to add a new point to a path on each touch, you can just call these two things on the first touchesBegan:

```
CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
                           lastPoint.x,
                           lastPoint.y);
```

And then call

```
CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 
                           currentPoint.x,
                           currentPoint.y);
```

on subsequent calls to -touchesBegan. Again, I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do.

One thing to note is that this is not doing anything:

```
currentPoint.x = currentPoint.x;
currentPoint.y = currentPoint.y;
```

And I don't see where your *mouseSwiped* variable is ever getting toggled (set to NO).

Comment: I'm using mouseSwiped for something else, but I want to instead draw tiled images that are rotated so that the images don't look like they are just being drawn constantly